# SAP custom translations for standard SAPUI5 application

Tags: sapui5, translation, sap-basis

I am currently implementing an extension to a standard application from SAP Marketing.

The extension contains new texts that need to be translated into different languages. In my previous extensions I could use the translation key of the standard application for my extension as well. The first line in the `i18n.properties` file in this case was always structured as follows:

```
# SAPUI5 TRANSLATION-KEY XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

However, in the standard app that I'm currently editing, it looks like this:

```
# This is the resource bundle for Campaigns 
# __ldi.translation.uuid = 8e965d5e-c905-4b60-ac2a-205abb14046
```

In transaction `se63`, the translation key (is it even a translation key?) is not found - either with hyphens or without. Furthermore, in the standard app, the translations are kept in a single file for each language (e.g., `i18n_de.properties`). That's why I'm not sure if there's even a translation key for this standard app.

I don't want to create a new translation key for my extension and use this one. Once I did this, all the translations of the standard app had to be maintained for the new translation key as well.

Is anyone familiar with this type of translation? How can I maintain the translations for my extension?

Best Regards,

Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some solution to my problem:

1. I generated a new translation key by running program `/UI5/TEXT_FILE_GEN_TRANS_KEY` in transaction `se38`
2. I created a new folder `i18n` and added a `i18nCustom.properties` file to it. Then I added the translation key and default translations to the file just like for a regular `i18n.properties` file.
3. In the next step, I added the following code to the `sap.ui5` property of the extension's `manifest.json` file to initiate the custom translation file:

   ```
   "models": {
       "i18nCustom": {
           "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
           "settings": {
               "bundleName": "<Your Component>.i18n.i18nCustom"
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Please note that you have to use something like `{i18nCustom>property}` in your view now instead of using `i18n` model.
4. To enhance the standard translation file with the custom one, I added the following code to the `BaseController`. You could also add the code only in the controller whose view is using the custom translations.

   ```
   onBeforeRendering: function() {
       var i18n = this.getModel("i18n"); // Get the standard i18n file
       var sBundleURL = this.getModel("i18nCustom").getResourceBundle().oUrlInfo.url;
       i18n.enhance({bundleUrl:sBundleURL}); // Merge the custom i18n file with the standard one
   }
   ```

Hope this helps if someone has the same problem.